# Wrong alignment in parallel text with \selectlanguage

Tags: babel, alignment, parallel-texts, babel-greek

An alignment problem occurs when I use Parallel Text together with \selectlanguage: the righthand column starts one or two lines below the lefthand column.

Here is a minimum working example of the problem

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gfsdidot}
\usepackage[english, greek, french]{babel}
\languageattribute{greek}{ancient}
\usepackage{parallel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{Parallel}{0.52\textwidth}{0.43\textwidth}

 \ParallelLText{ 
A \textit{deduction}, then, is a discourse in which,
certain things having been supposed, something different from the things supposed results of necessity through them. 
}
\ParallelRText{\raggedright
\selectlanguage{greek}
 Ἔστι δὴ συλλογισμὸς λόγος ἐν ᾧ τεθέντων τινῶν ἕτερόν τι τῶν κειμένων ἐξ ἀνάγκης συμβαίνει διὰ τῶν κειμένων. }
   \renewcommand{\ParallelAtEnd}{ \selectlanguage{english} \begin{flushright} \textit{Top.} I 1, 100a25--b23; transl. Smith modified \end{flushright}}
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

[image: The pdf output, with the alignment problem]

If I take the \selectlanguage out, and replacing the Greek by English, it is fine.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gfsdidot}
\usepackage[english, greek, french]{babel}
\languageattribute{greek}{ancient}
\usepackage{parallel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{Parallel}{0.52\textwidth}{0.43\textwidth}

 \ParallelLText{ 
A \textit{deduction}, then, is a discourse in which,
certain things having been supposed, something different from the things supposed results of necessity through them. 
}
\ParallelRText{\raggedright
A \textit{deduction}, then, is a discourse in which,
certain things having been supposed, something different from the things supposed results of necessity through them. 
 }
   \renewcommand{\ParallelAtEnd}{ \selectlanguage{english} \begin{flushright} \textit{Top.} I 1, 100a25--b23; transl. Smith modified \end{flushright}}
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

[image: The pdf output, without the alignment problem and without selectlanguage]

Note: The aligment problem is not due to the use of Greek, since I have the same problem using \selectlanguage{english} and the English text.

```
  \ParallelRText{\raggedright\selectlanguage{english} A
    \textit{deduction}, then, is a discourse in which, certain things
    having been supposed, something different from the things supposed
     results of necessity through them.   
    }
```

[image: The pdf output, with the alignment problem and \selectlanguage{english}]

Does anybody knows what is going on and how to fix this?
Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like the extra line is being produced when the block starts with `\selectlanguage`.  (It's not `\raggedright`, since you show an example with that, that lines up properly.)  I don't know how `\setlanguage` is defined, and haven't the time right now to explore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `\selectlanguage{greek}` that adds a blank line. Use `\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}...\end{otherlanguage*}` instead.

I propose a simpler interface:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gfsdidot}
\usepackage[main=english, greek, french]{babel}
\languageattribute{greek}{ancient}
\usepackage{parallel}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\NewDocumentEnvironment{xParallel}{mmo}
 {%
  \IfValueT{#3}{%
    \renewcommand{\ParallelAtEnd}{\begin{flushright}#3\end{flushright}}%
  }%
  \Parallel{#1}{#2}%
 }
 {\endParallel}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ParallelText}{mom}{%
  \csname Parallel#1Text\endcsname{%
    \IfValueT{#2}{\begin{otherlanguage*}{#2}}%
    #3\par
    \IfValueT{#2}{\end{otherlanguage*}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{xParallel}{0.52\textwidth}{0.43\textwidth}[
  \textit{Top.} I 1, 100a25--b23; transl. Smith modified
]
\ParallelText{L}{
  A \textit{deduction}, then, is a discourse in which,
  certain things having been supposed, something different
  from the things supposed results of necessity through them. 
}
\ParallelText{R}[greek]{\raggedright
   Ἔστι δὴ συλλογισμὸς λόγος ἐν ᾧ τεθέντων τινῶν ἕτερόν τι τῶν 
  κειμένων ἐξ ἀνάγκης συμβαίνει διὰ τῶν κειμένων.
}
\end{xParallel}

\end{document}
```

The `xParallel` environment has a trailing optional argument for setting the final text. The `\ParallelText` command has a mandatory argument for the side (`L` or `R`) and also an optional argument for the language.

[image]

The advantage is that it's possible to fine tune the spacings. For instance, you may want to do

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gfsdidot}
\usepackage[main=english, greek, french]{babel}
\languageattribute{greek}{ancient}
\usepackage{parallel}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{xParallel}{mmo}
 {%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \IfValueT{#3}{%
    \renewcommand{\ParallelAtEnd}{\par\nobreak\vspace{\topsep}{\raggedleft#3\par}}%
  }%
  \Parallel{#1}{#2}%
 }
 {\endParallel\par\addvspace{\topsep}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ParallelText}{mom}{%
  \csname Parallel#1Text\endcsname{%
    \IfValueT{#2}{\begin{otherlanguage*}{#2}}%
    #3\par
    \IfValueT{#2}{\end{otherlanguage*}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{xParallel}{0.52\textwidth}{0.43\textwidth}[
  \textit{Top.} I 1, 100a25--b23; transl. Smith modified
]
\ParallelText{L}{
  A \textit{deduction}, then, is a discourse in which,
  certain things having been supposed, something different
  from the things supposed results of necessity through them. 
}
\ParallelText{R}[greek]{\raggedright
   Ἔστι δὴ συλλογισμὸς λόγος ἐν ᾧ τεθέντων τινῶν ἕτερόν τι τῶν 
  κειμένων ἐξ ἀνάγκης συμβαίνει διὰ τῶν κειμένων.
}
\end{xParallel}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Tecti Uncomment the line with `\usepackage{xparse}` (but you should upgrade your TeX system).